# SharePoint - Site Usage Summary on Another Site?

Tags: site-usage

I want to place the Site Usage Summary for a site on another page (same site).  Is there an easy way to do this in SP 2007?

Comment: You'll get a better response to your question on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to achieve this - is to display your target page in an iframe on an other page.